# How to test Observable with auditTime() in Angular unit testing

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, jasmine

I have an observable in a component like this:

```
this.obs$ = this.someService.getMessage().pipe(auditTime(100),tap(do something))
```

and a test case like this:

```
mockService = jasmine.createSpyObj("SomeService", [
        "getMessage",
    ]);

mockService.getMessage.and.returnValue(of([]));

it("should get a value from service", fakeAsync(() => {
        let a;
        fixture.detectChanges();
        component.obs$.subscribe((b) => {
                   a=b; 
                  console.log(b)
        });
        tick(100);
        expect(a).toEqual(expectedValue);
    }
```

The service will return a subject$.asObservable();

However, no value is printed in console, and the test will fail as variable a is undefined

How do I test an observable with auditTime?

Comment: move your expect to your subscription

Comment: But the problem is the value never printed in console, which means the observable never get the value, and I get a warning saying that no expectation in the test case, so it won't work if I move the expect inside subscription.